# setFillColor with gradient

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a problem with set color in corona. Acording to parameter, color should be set as gradient (if 0) or solid color. But if I set it to gradient, I could not set it to solid color after. Here is a part of the code:

```
local function fillColor(tile, color)
if color==0 then
    local g = { type="gradient", color1={ 0, 0, 0 }, color2={ 0, 1, 0 } }
    tile:setFillColor(g)
elseif color==1 then
    tile:setFillColor(0.1,0.1,0.1)
elseif color==2 then
    tile:setFillColor(0.5,0.5,0.5)
elseif color==3 then
    tile:setFillColor(0.75,0.75,0.75)
end
```

Comment: "I could not set it to solid color after" What do you mean by this?

Comment: Do you know for a fact that `color` takes on a non-zero value?

Comment: After I set rectangle to be filled by gradient, I could not change it's filling to a plain color, without gradient.
Schollii: what do you mean? If I set color to (0, 0, 0) it is plain black. Of course if it is not set to gradient already.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly if the object gets filled by a gradient then you can never change it to a regular color.  Is that correct?

If so then just have the other colors be a gradient but have color1 and color2 be the same value.

Comment: You understood it correctly. This method works, but it is rather a workaround than solving.

Comment: Yeah it is just a workaround.  It sounds like you'll probably need to file a bug with Corona to see if they can't get that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In CoronaSDK setFillColor() with a gradient structure is done like this:

```
local gradient = {
    type="gradient",
    color1={ 1, 1, 1 }, 
    color2={ 0.8, 0.8, 0.8 }, 
    direction="down"
}

setFillColor(gradient)
```

I think you forgot the "direction" parameter.

Comment: gradient works nice ("down" direction is default), but covering it with solid (non gradient) color doesn't work